# In Symfony2, how can I refresh the page, changing just one parameter of the GET string?

Tags: symfony, get, request, query-string

How can I refresh the page, changing one parameter of the GET string?

Say I'm on this page:

```
/my/page?foo=bar&asd=qwe
```

And in the controller, I have this variable:

```
$var = array('foo' => 'woof');
```

How can I use that variable to redirect to this page?:

```
/my/page?foo=woof&asd=qwe
```

Or if I'm on this page:

```
/my/page
```

Using that variable, how do I get to this page?:

```
/my/page?foo=woof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, what you want to do is the following:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $params = $request->query->all();  // get the original GET parameters

    $var = array('foo' => 'woof');
    $newParams = array_replace($params, $var); // only replaces the 'foo' parameter, keeping the rest as is

    $url = '/my/page?'.http_build_query($newParams); // you can also use $this->generateUrl() if you use routing (which would be a good idea)

    return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event -> getRequest();
    $routes = $this -> router -> getRouteCollection();
    $routeName = $request -> get("_route");
    $params = $request -> query -> all();
    $route = $routes -> get($routeName);
    preg_match_all("/{(.+)}/", $route -> getPattern(), $routeParams);
    $routeParams = $routeParams[1];
    foreach ($routeParams as $key => $value) {
        $params[$value] = $request -> get($value);
    }

    if (array_key_exists("to_remove", $params)) {
        unset($params['to_remove']);
        $url = $this -> router -> generate($routeName, $params);
        $event -> setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```